# For Loop should run one time but it is not running

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, getline

When I enter "1", for loop should run one time. but it just prints "0". I don't know why.
I think the problem is with "getline(cin, input)" but i dont know the problem.
Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    string input;
    int t, output, occured_length, lenght, match;
    char occured[26];
    cin>>t;
    for(int i=0; i<t; i++)   //I am talking about this loop
    {
        occured_length = 0;
        getline(cin, input);   //This might be causing the problem
        lenght = input.size();
        for(int j=0; j<lenght; j++)
        {
            if(occured_length == 25)
            {
                cout<<"\n"<<occured_length+1;
                break;
            }
            match = 0;
            for(int k=0; k<occured_length; k++)
            {
                if(input[j] == occured[k])
                {
                    match= 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(match == 0)
            {
                occured_length++;
                occured[occured_length] = input[i];
            }
        }
        cout<<"\n"<<occured_length;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: occured_length is zero and that gets printed at last, do intialize match with some value before using it

Comment: can you please tell us the input you are providing at `cin>>t` and `getline(cin, input)`

Comment: You're right about problematic line. After reading integer `t`, `input` is read until end of line. You're still on the same line. That's why size of `input` is zero.

Comment: well for given code its working right.. i should only print `0` as its doing.. so what exatcly u want tell that first..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);
```

Gets line from input stream into string. It extracts characters from is and stores them into str until the the newline character, '\n' is found.
\n remains in the input stream, you need to another dummy input reading, otherwise you will get input = "" on next getline

```
cin>>t; 
char c;
cin >> c;
```

Answer (score 1):

input is empty & length is 0

Comment: @AliKazmi       why are you doing cin>> in your first for loop and getline in the other for loop? You are simply asking user to enter how many iterations your for loops will do. Can't you use the same mechanism?

Comment: cin>>t; This to enter the number of test cases.
getline(cin, input); this is to enter the string on which i will run tests.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after the input with using `operator >>`

```
cin>>t;
```

the input buffer will contain new line character. And next statement with getline

```
getline(cin, input);
```

reads an empty string.

You have to remove the new line character from the input buffer usig method ignore. For example

```
#include <limits>

//...


std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

The call of ignore should be before getline and after operator >>.